# Necesito crear un Stack -> Listview -> Positioned en Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Estoy necesitando crear el siguiente layout. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora tengo esto, pero por mas que trato de entender la lógica del orden de los widgets, no logro dar con lo que quiero.

```
      body: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        decoration: _recursos.backgroundImageComun(),
      ),
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              height: 196.0,
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: new List.generate(15, (int index) {
                       new Positioned(

                          child: new GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                randomizer(index);
                              },
                              child: new Container(
                                  width: 110.0,
                                  height: 196.0,
                                  child: new Image(
                                      image: new AssetImage(
                                          'assets/bgcard-a.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover))));
                    }),
                  )
                ],
              ))
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

UPDATE:

Si lo hago sin los elementos: ListView->Positioned->GestureDetector puedo hacerlo, pero no es la idea.

Necesito ponerlo en un listView por el Scroll horizontal, y generar los items dinamicamente por que la cantidad de cartas es variable. Y lógicamente usar el Positioned para darle el "margin" izquierdo.
Y al final el GestureDetector para trabajar la carta seleccionada. ESOS elementos, son los que no puedo hacerlos funcionar.

```
        body: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        decoration: _recursos.backgroundImageComun(),
      ),
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: 196.0,
            child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
              //ListView->GestureDetector->Positioned
              new Positioned(
                  left: 0.0,
                  child: new Container(
                      width: 110.0,
                      height: 196.0,
                      child: new Image(
                          image: new AssetImage('assets/bgcard-a.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover))),
              new Positioned(
                  left: 40.0,
                  child: new Container(
                      width: 110.0,
                      height: 196.0,
                      child: new Image(
                          image: new AssetImage('assets/bgcard-a.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover))),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: entiendo que es en modo landscape ?

Comment: has intentado usar Transform para la rotación ? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html

Comment: La rotación es lo de menos. Lo que no logro dar es con el orden correcto de los widgets. Lo del modo landcape o portrait también es lo de menos por que en el listview tiene el scroll horizontal.

Comment: el orden de los widgets es conforme lo vas poniendo en el stack, el último aparece encima

Comment: Si, eso lo entiendo, le hice un Update a mi pregunta, la verdad me está dejando pelado esto...

Comment: ya entiendo, dame unos minutos y te muestro un poco de código

Comment: tengo unos problemas haciendo el Stack scrolable, lo del contenido dinámico es sencillo, puedes probar con este plugin?  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_swiper

Comment: Si lo habia visto, pero no le di importancia por que pensé que era algo simple de realizar. La lógica me dice que ese tipo de cuestiones deben estar integradas en el core... Que opinas?

Comment: pues hay formas de hacerlo, usando GestureDetector , así lo hace esa librería, el Stack no puede tener un atributo scroll, sería muy complicado porque los items se pueden posicionar en cualquier lugar. Pero es una buena idea para implementar

Comment: Claro, alli viene mi problema. Habrá otra manera de darle un "margin" negativo sin usar Positioned? Ya lo tengo resuelto, solo que las cartas se muestran en fila una al lado de la otra y yo quiero que tengan esa vista, una sobre otra...

Comment: tampoco encuentro información, seguro hay que implementarlo manualmente con gesturedetector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo tengo, con la ayuda de unos amigos de Flutter , todo sin usar Stack basicamente el truco era el `Align` widget, tiene una propiedad `withFactor` en la que se puede cambiar el ancho del Widget por la proporción que le pongas.
Cree un item fake al final para que no se muestre cortado.

Aqui tienes el ejemplo básico.

```
    List<int> cardList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index >= cardList.length) {
                    return Align(
                      widthFactor: 0.5,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 80.0,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  final item = cardList[index];
                  return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    widthFactor: 0.5,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () => print("click on $item"),
                      child: 
                        child: Image(
                            width: 100.0,
                            height: 140.0,
                            image: new AssetImage('resources/naipe.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.contain),
                      ,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: cardList.length + 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se ve GENIAL! Voy a probarlo...Por cierto, que es? un Grupo? Estoy en uno de Gigacode de Facebook https://www.facebook.com/groups/flutter.dart.spanish/ y en uno de Gitter https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter

Comment: solo un workaround por si lo notas, al elemento fake que se crea, tambien ponle InkWell o gesturedetector para que reconozca el TAP, y usa el último elemento del a lista

Comment: Me referia a los amigos de Flutter que mencionaste :D

Comment: Es un grupo de Slack, me invitaron desde Twitter, la comunidad es muy activa, te dejo mi twitter twitter.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Es un grupo de Slack, me invitaron desde Twitter, la comunidad es muy activa, te dejo mi twitter twitter.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Funciona perfecto! muchas gracia!.Pasame ese grupo de Slack por favor!

Comment: Dejame tu mail por aca y se los paso para que te agreguen